# Is there a Rust function that returns all the maximum values of an iterator?

Tags: rust, iterator, max

I have a specific use case where I need to choose the maximum element from an `Iterator<Item = (i8, f64)>`. If there are multiple maximum elements in the Iterator I want to randomly select a maximum element uniformly distributed.

I tried the [`max_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.max_by) function for Iterators but it doesn't work as I need it because it always returns the last element if there a multiple maximum elements.
Here the example:

```
fn main() {
    let v = [(-1i8, 0.4f64), (0, 0.2), (1, 0.4)];
    let max = v.into_iter().max_by(|(_, r), (_, s)| r.total_cmp(s)).unwrap(); //always returns (1, 0.4)
    println!("{:?}", max);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dce2f6e113d3b7010656d387bd377ca0)

I need a function which returns another Iterator over the maximum elements. Then I could choose a random element from that Iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in std, but [in `itertools` there is](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.max_set):

```rust
iter.max_set();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have your comparison function return `Less` or `Greater` at random when the compared items are equal, with a suitable weighting to get uniform sampling:

```
use rand::{ self, Rng };
use std::cmp::Ordering;

let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
let mut count = 0;
let max = v.into_iter().max_by(move |(_, r), (_, s)| {
    match r.total_cmp(s) {
        Ordering::Equal => {
            count = count + 1;
            if rng.gen_range (0..=count) == 0 {
                Ordering::Less
            } else {
                Ordering::Greater
            }
        },
        Ordering::Less => {
            count = 0;
            Ordering::Less
        },
        Ordering::Greater => Ordering::Greater,
    }
}).unwrap();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=1fbbdc3e997464107270c23150e83d63)

Note however that this depends on the implementation of `Iter::max_by` (specifically on the order it passes arguments to the comparison closure), so you might need to rewrite it yourself (e.g. using [`Iter::fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) or [`Iter::reduce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.reduce)) to make sure of the order.

Comment: That's also a good approach. Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain the last part of your answer with the ordering in more detail? Why is order important here?

Comment: Order is important because if you want uniform sampling between all the maxima, then you need to weight your random selection in favor of the old maximum. So when the elements compare equal, you need to change the weights depending on whether `max_by` called `cmp (max, current)` (as shown in my example) or `cmp (current, max)`.